# How to add users to ASP user database?

Tags: asp.net

I have configured ASP user database. I can create users/roles either programmatically or by going to Project -> ASP.Net configuration in Visual Studio IDE.

Server this database is running on doesn't have VS installed. Is there a way to add users/roles through command line or IIS settings?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a simple site or an admin only page on your current site and use the **CreateUserWizard** control.  A Guide to customizing this control can be found here: https://web.archive.org/web/20211020103243/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/070506-1.aspx

Documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.aspx

You can also use the membership objects to do this through code if you want to create your own console application to do it from the command line.

**Do not try and do this in the database directly.**

Comment: Really like the command line idea. Quick and easy to implement. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you set the connection string properly you can use VisualStudio running locally to configure your remote asp.net membership database.
I do that all the time.
Make sure your connections strings are right on your Web.Config file.
This is the easiest unless you want to code it yourself.

*Edit *

Just to be clear, you are not required to have Visual Studio installed on the server which hosts the membership database.

**However** this only works if you are not storing any additional data per user which is not part of asp.net's MembershipUser class.
In most cases you would implement a register page where you would collect the additional info. On submit you create a new MembershipUser (using MembershipProvider API) and then persist the additional information as best suits your needs. I typically use the MembershipProvider and have an store my custom info in an AppUsers table, (with the asp.net userId as a FK).
Hope this helps ;-)

Using MembershipProvider and RoleProvider is very, very easy. Ask if you need some sample snippets.

Comment: +1 Because this is by far the easiest, and what I generally do.  This is probably the answer you are looking for. But if users need to be managed by someone other than the developer you should create a custom interface.

Answer (score 0):

you can just add them manually to the database tables, there not that hard to deduce, just apply insert commands using your favorite sql client

Comment: That's not so true.  You'll need to hash the passwords.